# std::array<char, N> to std::string

Tags: c++, arrays, string, c++11, std

What is the best way to convert from a `std::array<char, N>` to a `std::string`?

I have tried producing a template method but have had no luck. I think my C++ skills just aren't up to scratch. Is there an idiomatic way of doing this in C++?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I won't say it is the "best way", but *a way* is to use `std::string`'s [iterator constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string):

```
std::array<char, 10> arr;
... // fill in arr
std::string str(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));
```

Comment: Wow. Apologies for asking such a trivial question.

Comment: `std::array` also has `begin` and `end` as member functions.

Comment: Yeah, I was gonna answer `std::string(arr.begin(), arr.end())`. Too late.

Comment: @JonathanEvans: `std::begin` and `std::end` are meant to be super-generic, because they work on built-in arrays, as well as anything with `begin()` and `end()` member functions.

Answer (score 24):

If there is a null terminated string in the array so:

```
std::array<char, 4> arr = {'a','b','c',0};
std::string str(arr.data());
```

Comment: There is a `string(const char* s, size_t n);` which seems to work even without a null terminator.